# Javascript to Modify a function in HTML and reload the page

Tags: javascript, html, string, replace

I have one page HTML which part of it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(Social);


function Social() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Errors');
        data.addRows([
        ['bla', 53],
        ['bla', 5]

         ]);
        var options = {title:'Social',
                       width:600,
                       height:200,
                       animation:{
                         "startup": true,
                          duration: 1500,
                          easing: 'out'}
                        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('Social'));
        chart.draw(data, options);}
</script>
```

Upon loading this page it uses google to nicely show the rows in ColumnChart.

If I would change the line starting with "var chart" to this:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('Social'));
```

The html would show barchart.

I want to create a javascript button that will replace text in the html from ColumnChart to BarChart and reload the page, something like:

```
function myFunction() {
 document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("ColumnChart", "BarChart");
 location.reload();
}
```

But this reload the page with the initial values. If I don't add reload I don't see any difference of course.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you reload the page, it will get a fresh html page, why do you need to reload the page ?

Comment: I dont know the method i should use, i just need to reload the page with different values, 
where instead of :var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('Social'));

Ill have:
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('Social'));

Comment: Why don't you just add a script that overwrite this div? Reloading here is not an option, do you have the URL of the page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to make change and reload the page and keep the change as `GET` request will reload the page from the server. Instead, you want to inject a script and run it so you update the existing page, you can try to run this after the page as loaded to overwrite the `ColumnChart` :

```js
function socialBarChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Errors');
  data.addRows([
    ['bla', 53],
    ['bla', 5]
  ]);
  var options = {
    title:'Social',
    width: 600,
    height: 200,
    animation: {
      "startup": true,
      duration: 1500,
      easing: 'out'
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('Social'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

// Then call this :
socialBarChart()
```

> It is best practice to use camelCase with a lowercase first char for naming your function, otherwise, it look like a class constructor.